# Python typing - constrain list to only allow one type of subclass

Tags: python, python-typing

I have 3 simple classes like:

```py
class Animal(abc.ABC):
    ...

class Cat(Animal):
    ...

class Dog(Animal):
    ...
```

Then I have a function which is annotated as such:

```py
def speak(animals: List[Animal]) -> List[str]:
   ...
```

My problem is that I want to constrain the `List[Animal]` to only include one type of animal, so:

```py
speak([Dog(), Dog()]) # OK
speak([Cat(), Cat()]) # OK
speak([Cat(), Dog()]) # typing error
```

How would I annotate the `speak` function to allow for this? Is it even possible to do using typing or am I forced to check this at runtime?

I have tried to use the `List[Animal]` as above but that doesn't give me an error when calling `speak` like `speak([Cat(), Dog()])`.

I have also tried messing around with generics like `TypeVar('T', bound=Animal)` but this still allows me to pass in a `List` of any combination of subclasses.

Comment: You can define a constrained type variable `T = TypeVar('T', Cat, Dog)` that enumerates the known subclasses of Animal, then specify `list[T]` as the parameter type, but I'm sure that's not what you were hoping for.

Comment: Similar to @chepner but I think also `Union[List[Cat], List[Dog]]` would work... not optimal though I understand

Comment: Yeah, if there were type-level list comprehensions, something like `Union[List[T] for T in Animal.__subclasses__]` would probably be the solution.

Comment: If you want to constrain the function to only one type of subclass you will have to check at runtime anyway. Python's type hinting is called hinting for a reason; it will not raise an exception

Comment: @JanWillem That's a trivial observation that applies to any use of type hints. It doesn't mean that it's not possible to *provide* a way to specify the desired hint here.

Comment: Actually, type-level list comprehensions wouldn't be necessary, just a type checker that would understand `TypeVar('T', *Animals.__subclasses__())` to mean all known (to this point?) subclasses of `Animals` without actually executing the `__subclasses__` method. There could be some other issues to making that work that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Thanks, `TypeVar('T', Cat, Dog)` works, albeit with a somewhat cryptic mypy error:

'Value of type variable "T" of "speak" cannot be "Animal"'.

Now I am trying find a more elegant solution where I don't have to specify every subclass.

Comment: Maybe take a step back: why do you want to prohibit a mixture of subclasses in the first place?

Comment: Keep in mind that a central tenet of type theory is if B is a subtype of A, then a value of type B is *always* a value of type A as well. Subclassing is just *one* way to define a subtype.

Comment: Also: suppose you had some subclasses of `Cat`, like `Persian` and `Shorthair`. Would you consider `[Persian(), Cat(), Subhair()]` a valid argument to `speak`?

Comment: @chepner I have a use case that fits. When writing an `xs_to_ys` function like `dataclasses_to_dataframe`, the input collection (often) needs to be homogenous wrt the attributes on all contained objects. Since a child / sibling can have wildly different attributes or types, constraining each call to a single not-further-subclassed type makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider your issue to be not yet well defined. Once you start filling in a more concrete implementation of `Animal`, you're possibly going to arrive at a convincing solution.

Here, I'll reword your criteria for `speak` as it currently stands: You want it to accept a `list` of any individual subclass of `Animal`, but not `Animal` itself. Hopefully we can see why this doesn't make sense - there's nothing in your given code that suggests `Animal` *can* be distinguished from any subclass of `Animal`, at least from the point of view to what `speak` will do to the `list` of animals.

Let's provide some distinguishing features instead:

**Python 3.10**

```
import typing as t
from typing_extensions import LiteralString
from collections.abc import Sequence

Sound = t.TypeVar("Sound", bound=LiteralString)

class Animal(t.Generic[Sound]):
    def speak(self) -> Sound:
        ...

class Cat(Animal[t.Literal["meow"]]):
    ...

class Dog(Animal[t.Literal["bark"]]):
    ...

def speak(animals: Sequence[Animal[Sound]]) -> list[str]:
    return [animal.speak() for animal in animals]


>>> speak([Dog(), Dog()])  # OK
>>> speak([Cat(), Cat()])  # OK
>>>
>>> # mypy: Argument 1 to "speak" has incompatible type "List[object]"; expected "Sequence[Animal[<nothing>]]" [arg-type]
>>> # pyright: Argument of type "list[Cat | Dog]" cannot be assigned to parameter "animals" of type "Sequence[Animal[Sound@speak]]" in function "speak"
>>> # pyre: Incompatible parameter type [6]: In call `speak`, for 1st positional only parameter expected `Sequence[Animal[Variable[Sound (bound to typing_extensions.LiteralString)]]]` but got `List[Union[Cat, Dog]]`
>>> speak([Cat(), Dog()])
```

Note that although `mypy` doesn't complain about the signature `squeak(animals: list[Animal[Sound]])`, this is technically not type-safe; you may decide to append `Cat()` to `list[Dog]`. This is why `Sequence` is used (it is non-mutable and covariant in its element types).

Comment: This is very creative, but feels a bit smelly to me, in part because it hinders subclassing, as a `WhinyDog(Animal[t.Literal["whine"]])` would not count as a `Dog`. That behaviour might be what OP wants though, it's still unclear.

Comment: @ljmc If we really wanted a `WhinyDog` then `Dog` would need its type variables to be reworked, and you can have `class WhinyDog(Dog[t.Literal["whine"]])`. Yes, it is hard to see what OP wants - this is very implementation dependent.